# Examining and challenging the IS-OUGHT gap and the FACT-VALUE dichotomy

Tags: ethics

Could anyone recommend undergrad-level intro papers or secondary literature on the is-ought gap and fact-value dichotomy please?
Keen to read examinations and challenges.
thanks

Comment: See [SEP, The Is-Ought Gap and the Fact-Value Distinction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thick-ethical-concepts/#OughGapFactValuDist) and references there. You'll have to add context, explain what you want this for, and make the request more focused for more substantive recommendations.